# An extremal sum for hypergraph degrees

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider a rank-$r$ hypergraph $H = (V,E)$. I would a lower-bound of the following form:
$$
\sum_{e \in E} \frac{ \sum_{v \in e} \text{deg}(v) }{\max_{v \in e} \text{deg}(v)} \geq c \sum_{v \in V} \text{deg}(v)
$$
where $c$ is as large as possible -- preferably a constant or something of the form $1/\text{polylog}(r)$.

It seems intuitively that such a bound should hold. For, if all the vertices have approximately equal degree $d$, then the LHS sums to $\sum_{e \in E} |e| = \sum_{v \in V} \deg(v)$. On the other hand, if there is a single vertex $v$ of very high degree $d$, and the other vertices have small degree, then the LHS sums to approximately $d$ and so does the RHS.

What value of $c$ can be shown here?

Comment: Of note, $\frac{r-1}{r} \geq c$. We can choose $(r−1)$ vertices appearing in all the edges, and the other $(|V|−r+1)$ vertices be in exactly one edge each.

Comment: If all $d$ edges share a common vertex and other vertices are different, the LHS equals $d+r-1$ and the RHS equals $cdr$. Thus $c$ is at most $1/r$ (such $c$ of course works.)

Comment: @ Feodor, I guess this refutes my conjecture -- thanks.